# Unity 2d Input lag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2d open world game with physics similar to that of stardew valley, but for some reason there's a lot of input lag on the character even when I remove all the other scripts and animations.

I even tried removing most of the sprites such as houses and whatnot but it still has a lot of lag, not framerate lag, just the player movement.

I will attempt to explain: If you just lightly tap the keyboard the player moves and stops just fine, but if you hold down the button then let go (for about 5s gives the most lag, doesn't get any worse after that), the player keeps moving a little after you let go of the key.

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementControls : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;
    private Vector2 MoveSpeed;
    private Rigidbody2D Player;

    void Start() {
        Player = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void Update() {
        Vector2 PlayerInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        MoveSpeed = PlayerInput.normalized * speed;
    }
    void FixedUpdate() {
        Player.MovePosition(Player.position + MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what fixed the problem to anyone else with said problem:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementControls : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed; //Change the player's speed
    private Vector2 MoveSpeed; //This is what the player's speed will be set to after some math
    private Rigidbody2D Player; //The player

    void Start() {
        Player = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); //Find the player GameObject
    }
    void Update() {
        Vector2 PlayerInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical")); //Get input
        MoveSpeed = PlayerInput * speed; //Math
        Player.MovePosition(Player.position + MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); //Move the player
    }
}
```